# how to use If let in optional photo?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swift3

So, my app crash because it forces to unwrap the "photo" even if it is optional and it has nothing inside. How do I use the if let statement, like if the photo has a picture then it will show, and if none it will be nil but the app wont crash.
I have this struct User this is where my data is saved I am using firebase.

```
struct User {

    var fullName: String!
    var username: String?
    var email: String!
    var country: String?
    var photoURL: String?
    var biography: String?
    var uid: String!
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var key: String?

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        key = snapshot.key
        ref = snapshot.ref

        fullName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["fullName"]  as! String
        email = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["email"]  as! String
        uid = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["uid"] as! String
        country = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["country"] as! String?
        biography = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["biography"] as! String?
        photoURL = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["photoURL"] as! String?
        username = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary) ["username"] as! String?
    }

}
```

this is where the app crashes, because of the "self.storageRef.reference(forURL:imageURL!)" it forces to unwrap even it has nothing inside.

```
 func loadUserInfo() {

 @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var country: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var biography: UILabel!

          let userRef = dataBaseRef.child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)")
            userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
                self.username.text = user.username
               self.country.text = user.country
                self.biography.text = user.biography
                self.fullName.text = user.fullName
                var imageURL =  user.photoURL

self.storageRef.reference(forURL:imageURL!).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imgData, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let data = imgData {
                            self.userImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: ctrl-f, "!" => 37 matches. Nope.

Comment: You are using toooooo many exclamation and question marks, some of them are even contradiction in terms.

Comment: Why are your IBOutlets inside of the function loadUserInfo() ?

Comment: Also user.photoURL is a String, not a URL

Comment: everything workouts fine man, it is in the loadUserInfo cause it's in the profile page, when the user clicks the profile it will show the  fullname,username, country, biography and picture, but the picture forces to unwrap. my problem here is just how to use the if-let in var imageURL = user.photoURL, cause it forces to unwrap it always

Comment: solved my problem already, thank you guys for your help. its optional chaining forces to unwrap. 
 var imageURL =  user.photoURL
 if let newImageUrl = imageURL {
                print(newImageUrl)
            
            
            self.storageRef.reference(forURL:newImageUrl).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imgData, error) in

Answer (score 0):

first I think you should change the `init` of the User, you should do:

```
let data = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary;
fullName = data["fullName"] as! String;
```

if you not sure the `country` whether exist, you could do:

```
country = data["country"] as? String;
```

then you could use `let` to keep save when you use the `use.photoURL`, just like:

```
if let photoURL = user.photoURL {
     //...retrive photo of the url from somewhere
}
```

finally, I wanna say, you maybe make a mistake understand about the `?` and `!`, or confusion with them.

`?` is when you think this variable/func maybe nil/can not be called, or when you make a type conversion, but you don't sure that must be success.

`!` is that you are sure it's exist or you will create it immediatelly. also you could comprehend it as unwrap the optional value, just cause of you make it absolute exist.

when we create our own model just like your `User`, you could make the columns impossible nil, you can do:

```
var fullName: String?       = nil;
fullName = SomeJsonTypeData["fullName"] ?? "default value";
```

then when you use it, you dispense with any worry about it will be `nil`.

Comment: thank you abel, but everything here is working fine. it's just i dont know what to put in the  "if let photoURL =  user.photoURL" like if the photoURL has a photo it will show the photo and if it doesnt have a photo it will just remain blank but the app wont crash

Comment: You should not use semicolon in Swift.

Comment: @Cookingcodes first, about the "?" and "!" usage, I just wanna give you a suggestion, cause of your code looks so confused, you should make clear with them, otherwise maybe some unexpected problems will occur in the future. And then the "if let photoURL = user.photoURL" will check if user.photoURL whether exist url or something else you or others defined, if not, it will not goes into the statement inside the "if", so tha app wont crash and the UIImageView or other components just keep blank cause of you do not supply UIImage or CGImage for it. so you can put a placeholder image to avoid blank

Comment: @chengsam yeah i know. but i am using many languages in my work. some of them must be using but some not. so i wanna make unification, to avoid i do forget in the other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If just focusing on the `photoURL` issue, I think this may help you:

```
if let imageURL = user.photoURL {
    self.storageRef.reference(forURL: imageURL).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imgData, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = imgData {
                    self.userImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It forces to unwrap! but I solved my problem already thank you though.
here's the answer.

if let newImageUrl = imageURL {
                print(newImageUrl)
    self.storageRef.reference(forURL:newImageUrl).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion